# Set up a crawler and downloaded tweets. Unable to parse JSON file

Tags: python, json, parsing, twitter

I have been trying to parse a JSON file and it keeps giving me additional data errors. Since I am new to Python, I have no idea how I can resolve this. It seems there are multiple objects within the file. How do I parse it without getting any errors?

Edit: (Not my code but I am trying to work on it)

```
import json
import csv
import io

 '''
creates a .csv file using a Twitter .json file
the fields have to be set manually
'''

data_json = io.open('filename', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read() #reads in 
the JSON file
data_python = json.loads(data_json)

csv_out = io.open('filename', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') #opens csv file


fields = u'created_at,text,screen_name,followers,friends,rt,fav' #field 
names
csv_out.write(fields)
csv_out.write(u'\n')

for line in data_python:

#writes a row and gets the fields from the json object
#screen_name and followers/friends are found on the second level hence two 
get methods
row = [line.get('created_at'),
       '"' + line.get('text').replace('"','""') + '"', #creates double 
quotes
       line.get('user').get('screen_name'),
       unicode(line.get('user').get('followers_count')),
       unicode(line.get('user').get('friends_count')),
       unicode(line.get('retweet_count')),
       unicode(line.get('favorite_count'))]

row_joined = u','.join(row)
csv_out.write(row_joined)
csv_out.write(u'\n')




csv_out.close()
```

Edit 2: I found another recipe to parse it but there is no way for me to save the output. Any recommendations?

```
import json
import re

json_as_string = open('filename.json', 'r')
# Call this as a recursive function if your json is highly nested
lines = [re.sub("[\[\{\]]*", "", one_object.rstrip()) for one_object in 
json_as_string.readlines()]

json_as_list = "".join(lines).split('}')
for elem in json_as_list:
if len(elem) > 0:
    print(json.loads(json.dumps("{" + elem[::1] + "}")))
```

Comment: Updated with code.Unable to parse the file properly. Need to be able to get a good output so I can analyse it.

Comment: What version of python do you use? And could you show the traceback - without that it's hard to help you...

Comment: Using python 2.7. Is it OK if I paste this tomorrow? Been at it since morning. Around one am here.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jest/PycharmProjects/untitled/token.py", line 14, in <module>
    data_python = json.loads(data_json)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 310, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 349, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 1201 column 1 (char 13339 - 8801096)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: So for loading the json read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199213/8240959. For extracting data from json look at answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218931/8240959.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials online on how to work with json in python. Google around and take some time getting the gradp of it. Look at this for instance: http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/python-json-module-tutorial.php. If you need help on extracting specific element from your tweet file, please show the json object that you need to extract from. Without that it's impossible to help you further.

Comment: Would a link to an example JSON file help?

Comment: Sure - if the structure in the example is identical to the one in your file...