# how can i extract one field from json file and print it into differnet file in python

Tags: json, python-2.7

i am trying to load JSON file and want to extract a field(only want frametime less that 4 sec) called frame time from that file and want to print it in different file in python, how can i do it?

piece of json file

[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2019-03-14",
    "_type": "pcap_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "frame": {
          "frame.encap_type": "1",
          "frame.time": "Mar  5, 2019 17:51:00.270140000 India Standard Time",
          "frame.offset_shift": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_epoch": "1551788460.270140000",
          "frame.time_delta": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_delta_displayed": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_relative": "0.000000000",
          "frame.number": "1",
          "frame.len": "99",
          "frame.cap_len": "99",
          "frame.marked": "0",
          "frame.ignored": "0",
          "frame.protocols": "eth:ethertype:ip:tcp",
          "frame.coloring_rule.name": "TCP",
          "frame.coloring_rule.string": "tcp"
        },
        "eth": {
          "eth.dst": "00:1a:11:00:00:02",
          "eth.dst_tree": {
            "eth.dst_resolved": "Google_00:00:02",
            "eth.addr": "00:1a:11:00:00:02",
            "eth.addr_resolved": "Google_00:00:02",
            "eth.lg": "0",
            "eth.ig": "0"
          },
          "eth.src": "00:1a:11:00:00:01",
          "eth.src_tree": {
            "eth.src_resolved": "Google_00:00:01",
            "eth.addr": "00:1a:11:00:00:01",
            "eth.addr_resolved": "Google_00:00:01",
            "eth.lg": "0",
            "eth.ig": "0"
          },
          "eth.type": "0x00000800"

Comment: Either upload the code you've written till now or share the json data that you're trying to read.

Comment: Similiar to :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218173/extract-part-of-data-from-json-file-with-python.
Have a look!