# How to pass data dynamically from JSON file to Selenium automated login with Python

Tags: python, json

So I'm using Python and I have a JSON file that has usernames and passwords in the following format

```
{
"username": {
    "0": "user1",
    "1": "user2",
    },
"password": {
    "0": "user1pass",
    "1": "user2pass",
    }
}
```

I'm trying to import credentials from the JSON file into Selenium

```
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
username.send_keys("test")
password.send_keys("test")
```

so for example it would pull data of User 1 from the JSON file and pass it into the username field, login then do smth,, then log out and pull the second user etc

I want to do a loop that can extract data from JSON and **also work with Selenium** to use the data and go to next data etc..not just pulling the data.

What should I be looking for exactly?

Comment: Is it JSON or Python dict?

Comment: @JaSON it's a JSON dictionary

Comment: I'm not sure what *JSON dictionary* is...) but I hope you already convert [JSON to dict](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-dictionary-in-python/)

Comment: @JaSON sorry I meant it's just a JSON file yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract part of data from JSON file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218173/extract-part-of-data-from-json-file-with-python)

Comment: There are python libraries built to read JSON from files... have you tried one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a loop of numbers which then in each iteration finds the login form and using loop variable chooses username and password then do things that you want.

```py
credentials_dict = {
"username": {
    "0": "user1",
    "1": "user2",
},
"password": {
    "0": "user1pass",
    "1": "user2pass",
}
for i in range(0,2):
    username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
    password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
    username.send_keys(credentials_dict['username'][str(i)])
    password.send_keys(credentials_dict['password'][str(i)])
    # do things that you want to do.
```

Comment: This solved it, except that it's JSON file not a python dictionary but I got the idea now how to work with the loop thank you